Difference between amidi -l and aconnect -l
I would like to use fluidsynth as a player for my Java application. However, fluidsynth creates a port visible via aconnect -l but invisible via amidi -l. Java MIDI, in turn, sees only the ports listed by amidi -l. So as it is, the connection in question seems impossible.
I know that amidi lists "hardware" ports and aconnect lists "sequencer/virtual hardware" (?) ports but I do not know why two separate spaces.
Is there a robust (in particular, initialized with a script and not with a mouse) configuration which makes it possible for a Java application (or any other which sees only the amidi ports) to use Fluidsynth?
